# Remove unused SASS from AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, sass, gruntjs, gulp, uncss

I've inherited an Angular1 Project that has bloated SASS files that need to be cleaned. Is there a way to automate the removal of unused SASS statements, either from production (during the build) or ideally, more permanently removed from development. I know there are tools like UNCSS that work well with static HTML pages, but it doesn't seem to work well with dynamic content.

Short of manual fixes, is there anything that can be done with regards to cleaning and removing unused SASS statements?

Comment: do you have a lot of generated classes ? Because has you said, UNCSS is an option and you might specify the generated classes so they don't get stripped off.

Comment: Uncss doesn't parse sass, just css. It can work with dynamic content (as in server-side rendering), it just doesn't work as well if you are adding a lot of classes with JS during user interaction.